# How to declare a reflection-iterable set of functions in Kotlin?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I want to declare a set of Kotlin functions that are *not* member functions of a class (i.e. „static“ functions without reference to a class instance). They have to be declared in a way so that I can iterate over them using reflection during runtime.

My first try was to write a file `Commands.kt` like this:

```
fun a(): Int = 42
fun b(): Int = 23
```

However, I did not find a way to iterate over the functions in this file. I know that for Java compatibility, a class `CommandsKt` will be generated that contains those functions as static methods. However, I seem not to be able to reference that class in Kotlin, neither did I find a way to iterate over all entities of a Kotlin file via reflection.

My second try was to use an object:

```
object Commands {
    fun a(): Int = 42
    fun b(): Int = 23
}
```

I can iterate over the member functions via `Commands::class.declaredMemberFunctions` now. However, those functions would still be member functions, not „static“ (in Java speak) functions (right?).

So how would I declare those functions so that they are both static and iterable via reflection?

Answer (score 3):

If you annotate the functions declared in an `object` with `@JvmStatic`, they will be compiled to static Java methods.

Comment: So says the manual. However, I cannot retrieve them using `Commands::class.staticFunctions`; instead, they are available as `Commands::class.functions` and actually take an `INSTANCE` parameter.

Comment: The bytecode has both declarations for each such function - the static one and the one that takes `INSTANCE` as a parameter. I guess the Kotlin reflection sees only the latter one...

Comment: Well, my question was about availability via reflection, and it doesn't help me that the static method is there in the byte code.

Answer (score 1):

> I seem not to be able to reference that class in Kotlin

`Class.forName("your.package.CommandsKt")` will work (it returns `java.lang.Class`, not `KClass`; I am not sure if calling `.kotlin` on it will work).

Comment: Calling `.kotlin` works on any Java class, regardless of how it was compiled.

Comment: I will go with this solution, the code looks cleaner with it.

Comment: @yole Good to know. That's what I assumed initially but then realized I was only assuming and didn't have opportunity to test.

Comment: @yole I was a bit too fast when accepting this answer. It actually doesn't work: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Packages and file facades are not yet supported in Kotlin reflection. Meanwhile please use Java reflection to inspect this class`. So if I want to use *Kotlin* reflection, the other answer is the right one.